# How to do a SELECT with multiple columns from an SQLCE database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, sql-server-ce, local-database

Because my last question didn't return anything useful, I will have to ask yet another question.

The situation:

I have a local SQLCE database. It contains 2 tables; "Artikels" and "Leggers" (Don't mind the Dutch names, doesn't change the situation). The table I'll be querying has the columns "Artikelnummer", "Omschrijving", "Legger", and "Voorraad".

What I want to do:

Query the table "Artikels" for "Artikelnummer" and "Omschrijving" and then display it in a CheckedListbox, preferably with two seperate columns (or just one if it doesn't work with multiple).

The code I have put together from tutorials and answers here:

```
private void populateListbox()
    {
        string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.Database;

        string selectString = "select artikelnummer, omschrijving from Artikels";

        SqlCeDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();


            using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand(selectString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string dataTableName = "Artikels";

                sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(selectString);


                DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[dataTableName];

                listboxGeselecteerd.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[dataTableName];
                listboxGeselecteerd.ValueMember = "[Artikelnummer]";
                listboxGeselecteerd.DisplayMember = "[Omschrijving]"; 

                connection.Close();
            }

    }
```

I don't get any errors, but while debugging I have seen that nothing is happening from  `DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[dataTableName];` on.

I have googled it, but nothing I have read mentioned selecting multiple columns.

I am using VS2010, by the way.

Comment: What do you mean “nothing is happening”? Is `dataSet.Tables[dataTableName]` `null`?

Comment: i answered in you past question check it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've forgotten to call the `Fill` method:

```
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Comment: Where exactly should this be?

Comment: After opening the connection and setting the `SelectCommand`.

Comment: Alright, got that. Now it's skipping all the code that follows in that function.

Comment: If the method is executing snychronously, that shouldn't be possible. Is it falling into a catch or something?

Comment: I got the last lines of code from another question. When I was typing those lines, IntelliSense didn't help me. But VS does accept those lines. Maybe they're a problem?